# Why doesn't textfill work in this situation?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to re-size a text to fix a fixed size div and I found the textfill plugin that seemed perfect for it, except that I can't get it to work for some reason:

html:

```
<script src="Scripts\jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts\jquery.textfill.min.js"></script>

<div id="textfilltest">
    <div id="name1"><span>Name 1</span></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name1").textfill();
});
</script>
```

css:

```
#name1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
    top: 30%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

when I write more text, it goes down a line instead of resizing, I have no idea why it would do that

edit: [here's a link to the website](http://googledrive.com/host/0ByBwY60ZsbQpZjFJaDhTQlRfdTg/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent line wrapping using jQuery textfill, add a `line-height` equal to `height`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name1").textfill();
});
```

```css
#name1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
    top: 30%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-textfill.github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery.textfill.min.js"></script>
<div id="textfilltest">
  <div id="name1"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you link in the jQuery source?  (It should come *before* the textfill source).  Try replacing your script source with the two in my Snippet.

Comment: that didn't fix it either, and [it is linked before jQuery](http://i.imgur.com/d4bYJMI.png)

Comment: Hmm, I may need to see your site or your full source code to know what the problem is.

Comment: I see the problem.  `nomEquipe1` is not visible when you call `textfill` on it.  A quick fix is to add this code immediately before the `textfill` call:  `$("#nomEquipe1").parent().parent().show();`

Comment: I did the same thing and it worked, but if you go at the end of the script tag at the end of the HTML page, you can see that I already call it, so I'm confused

Comment: yup, that fixed it, out of curiosity though, do you know what's causing this to happen?

Comment: The element has to be visible in order for `textfill` to fit a font to its width.  Perhaps one of `nomEquipe1`'s parents is hidden.  (It's a lot of code to go through, but the site looks great!)

Comment: one of his parents has this `display: none; overflow: hidden;` I'm guessing that's the one?

Comment: Yes, that would cause the problem.

Comment: This totally saved me, I've been pulling my hair out for 2 days. @RickHitchcock

Answer (score 3):

I tried out your code  and by changing the css to

```
#name1 {
    position:static;
    left: 75px;
    top: 30%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

it seems to work fine

Comment: that didn't fix it for me, weird

Comment: yeah ... u have added  jquery.js rigth??

Comment: yup: `<script src="Scripts\jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: does it still goes down after changing the position css to static

Comment: yes, all it seems to do is clip the text to the left side of the screen, and I can't see half of the text because of that :/